# Does the order of element of a vector matter in the context of linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

Per this [stanford handouts](https://web.stanford.edu/class/nbio228-01/handouts/Ch4_Linear_Algebra.pdf)

> A vector is a list of numbers.

consider these 2 two vectors

$\vec x_1 = [3,  1.1,  0.12]$

$\vec x_2 = [3,  0.12, 1.1]$

Is it reasonable to say $\vec x_1$ is equal to $\vec x_2$? In other words, does the order of element of a vector matter in the context of linear algebra?

Answer (score 0):

The order of the elements in a vector matters ! Hence $\vec x_1 \ne \vec x_2.$

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not reasonable. The definition uses the word "list" not "set", explicitly because the order matters.

Comment: Thank you! Is the word "list" a canonical term or just a plain English word?

Answer (score -1):

To build on Fred's answer, when the vectors lie in R^3, they can be thought of as "directions." For example:

x_1 is telling you to travel 3 units east, 1.1 units north, and 0.12 units up.

x_2 is telling you to travel 3 units east, 0.12 units north, and 1.1 units up.

Although you did the same amount of traveling, you end up in a different location. So the vectors aren't equal.

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter could comment on an issue with this answer?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).